# Scheduling jobs with high CPU load in Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, scheduling, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET to schedule a job which loads a bunch of data from external sources and persists in a database. After downloading them some processing have to be on them too, which will create additional records in a different table in the database.

The downloader job is a stateful job and runs in every minute. The problem I've faced is that, after downloading the data the processing part of it could take much longer time than I expected.

How should I manage this? I've though about creating another job (which will run for one time only) when the data downloading finishes. In this case the downloader job can run in every minute (this was the original plan), because the download part takes 5-20 secs only, and the other job can process these records after the downloader one has finished. The processer job would fetch records marked as unprocessed from database and do the work on them.

Is this a correct approach to handle the processing? The other idea I came is to set up a WCF service which would process one downloaded element. This would be called on each downloaded element. However I don't think this would perform better than the other job approach.

Comment: Is the `processing part` CPU bound operation or does it involve heavy IO operations as well?

Comment: Under high load I meant CPU load, so there is no heavy IO in the process.

Comment: Ok, so can you try to do this processing parallel using TPL and see if you gain anything so that it is done in acceptable time

Comment: So you mean to use TPL in the Quartz.NET job which is also responsible for downloading? I will try out how fast that will be but I want to stay in the 1 minute time frame in order to not delay the next downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to having the download job schedule another job to do the processing is feasible and used commonly.

One thing to keep in mind though is that this works as long as the download job doesn't always schedule a processing job. If your download job always schedules a job (say every minute) and the scheduled job takes longer than that to run, you will eventually run out of processing threads and your download job will have to wait for a thread to be available.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't thought about the possible issue you mentioned. Is there any "recommended" strategy or method to prevent this situation?

Comment: You could run the long-running jobs on a different scheduler, with perhaps enough capacity so that you don't run out of threads.

Comment: Thanks. If I set the downloader jobs priority to high, and low on the processing, that wouldn't solve it? I guess not if you suggested to run them on a different scheduler, but worth to ask.

Comment: Priority is only used to break ties when 2 triggers need to fire at the exact same time, so this wouldn't solve the problem. Quartz.net runs jobs in order based on the trigger's next fire time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a better approach should be using the job as an event, and have another service execute the download.

The job would just send a message defining the intent to another endpoint.

This is very common in an Event Driven Architecture with some sort of message broker or service bus, like NServiceBus or MassTransit.

That way your scheduler will remain lean and scalable.

Here is an example:

```
public class DownloadFileJob : IJob
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }
    public ILogger Logger{ get; set; }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Bus.Send(new DownloadFileMessage());
        Logger.Info("Sending message requesting download of file.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might look into setting up a [`JobListener`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_7.html) for the download job.  Simply create a class that implements the `IJobListener` interface, then put your processing code in the `JobWasExecuted` method:

```
public PostDownloadJobListener : IJobListener
{
    string Name { get { return "MyJobListener"; } }
    void JobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) { }
    void JobExecutionVetoed(JobExecutionContext context) { }
    void JobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException)
    {
        // Perform processing here
    }
}
```

Register the listener using `scheduler.AddJobListener(myJobListener);`, and let the listener do the processing after the job successfully executes.